# Flex: preventing tree's vertical scroll bar overlapping view

Tags: apache-flex, tree, scrollbar, overlap

I have an `mx:Tree`, but when the vertical scroll bar appears, it overlaps the content of the tree (odd that the horizontal bar does not). That might be acceptable for the text, but the stripe that I create using the item renderer, for certain items, seems to make it an anathema to the QA guys. How can I keep this from happening?

I have an *idea* for a workaround: I could make use the item renderer to stop the drawing a little bit short of the right side of the view (not that I can reliably get the width of a scroll bar) but I can't even figure out how wide the displayable part of a tree is--all the properties of a tree seem to be about its entire width, which includes the entire area coverable using the horizontal scroll bar. However, the blue stripe signifying a selected item doesn't seem to have that problem--it stops short of the scroll bar. In any case, when trying to find the displayable region, I don't know if I could handle the added complication of when the horizontal scroll bar is moved. Much better if someone could tell me how to put the veritcal bar outside the displayable tree area (or shrink the displayable area, of course). Thanks.

I'm using the Flex 3.5 SDK

Comment: It's been so long since I've hacked any of this stuff that all I can tell you is keep hitting F3 on the "extends" part of the Tree Class and its ancestors until you find who draws the selection indicator, then see how it knows how wide to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution when researching [horizontal scrollbar issue on list and tree component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076842/horizontal-scrollbar-issue-on-list-and-tree-component/2076909#2076909). The blog to which it links eventually shows a kind of hacky solution (in the readers' comments) that shows how to make sure that none of the drawing is done beyond a certain boundary.